# Help applying a fade to background-position change with Jquery

Tags: jquery, hover, background-position

I'm very new to Jquery but have finally worked out how to change the background-image (a sprite) of my #contentContainer when hovering over a separate 'trigger' image. However, for the life of me I cannot work out how to apply a fade effect to the transition. Basically, instead of the current abrupt background image transition I would like it to fade in smoothly on mouseover and mouseout.

Here is my (non fading but working) script:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
$j("#swapTrigger").hover(
function() {
$j("#contentContainer").css("background-position", "0px 1401px");    
},
function() {
$j("#contentContainer").css("background-position", "0px 0px");  
});
});
```

Very many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Try using http://api.jquery.com/animate

```
 $j("#contentContainer").animate({"background-position": "0px 1401px"}, "slow");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Stefan - unfortunately I have not been able to get it to work though (as with Pat's suggestion above). Seems odd - no idea why... The only thing I can think of (very limited knowledge of javascript) is is it possible that because my hover trigger element is separate from the element to be changed (the contentContainer) that the script syntax should be slightly different from the examples shown? Would that perhaps explain why my non-fading script works but both the fading versions do not?

Thanks again!

Comment: Could you edit in your last version? Maybe I can see something.

Answer (score 3):

You can animate the background position property, which will give you a smooth transition between the 2 images:

```
$j("#swapTrigger").css({backgroundPosition: "0 0"}); 
$j("#swapTrigger").hover(
    function() {
        $j("#contentContainer").animate({backgroundPosition: "0 1401px"});    
    },
    function() {
        $j("#contentContainer").animate({backgroundPosition: "0 0"});  
    }
);
```

If your question is about fading the opacity of the images as they switch between the 2, you can't do it with a single element.  You'll need to add your background image to nested elements and then fade them in and out:

```
<div id="contentContainer">
    Some content
    <div class="bg1"></div>
    <div class="bg2"></div>
</div>
```

On hover, fade them in and out as required:

```
var bg1 = $('.bg1');
var bg2 = $('.bg2');
$j("#swapTrigger").hover(
    function() {
        if(bg1.is(':hidden')){
           bg1.stop().fadeIn();
           bg2.stop().fadeOut();
        } else {
           bg2.stop().fadeIn();
           bg1.stop().fadeOut();
        }   
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Pat. Unfortunately your first solution, which sounded like the ideal solution is not working for me - no idea why (have tried it several times). May try your second method, although would prefer not to be adding to my markup (as its working ok in all browsers at the mo!).

Thanks again!

Comment: I completely understand not wanting to add more markup.  Check out my edits to see if they'll help you.  I added an explicit set of the background-position before the animation.  Out of curiosity, does your background position animate at all when you mouseover your `#swapTrigger` element?